# how to get regex matching occurring from the given string? (example attached)

Tags: regex

How could I update this regex so it only matches (providing the Group "CustomerName"s) from the starting point marked by "START"?  (using Global & Multiline setting)

Current regex:

```
(Mr)\s*(?<CustomerName>.*)\b
```

Text to Scan

```
qwer asdf asdf
Mr Bill Smith
qwer asdf asdf
  Mr Bob Smith
  START  
qwer asdf asdf
  Mr Correct1 Smith  
qwer asdf asdf
  Mr Correct2 Smith  
asldfj asldf
```

So instead of matching four names, it should only match the last two names =>

- Group CustomerName:  Correct1 Smith
- Group CustomerName:  Correct2 Smith

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?

Comment: for the sake of this question assume no, just using effectively https://regex101.com/ with Global and MultiLine flag.   So very interested so see if this can be done with basic regex or not...

Comment: I'm curious too. I've encountered this problem and struggled for half-day without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=^\s*START\s*$[\s\S]*\n\s*)Mr\s+(?<CustomerName>.*\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Lookbehind assertion

  - `^\s*START\s*$` Match START between optional whitespace chars
  - `[\s\S]*\n\s*` Match any char 0+ times, then match a newline and optional whiteapace chars
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `Mr\s+` Match Mr and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?<CustomerName>.*\S)` Named group *CustomerName* Match the rest of the line, ending in a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w42LuO/1)

Or using the `\G` anchor

```
(?:^\s*START\s*|\G(?!^))(?:\n(?!\s*Mr).*)*\n\s*Mr\s+(?<CustomerName>.*\S).*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^\s*START\s*` Match START between optional whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match
- `)`Close the non capture geoup
- `(?:` non capture group

  - `\n(?!\s*Mr).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with Mr
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat it
- `\n\s*Mr\s+` Match a newline and Mr
- `(?<CustomerName>.*\S)` Named group *CustomerName* Match the rest of the line, ending in a non whitespace char
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TJrsCG/1)

Comment: thanks - your second suggestion worked straight away - i.e. "(?:^\s*START\s*|\G(?!^))(?:\n(?!\s*Mr).*)*\n\s*Mr\s+(?<CustomerName>.*\S).*".       [got "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width" for the first suggestion]

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses a lookbehind with a quantifier which surprisingly ECMAScript can do yet PCRE and Python cannot.

```js
/(?<=START[\s\S]+)\n  (Mr.+ .+\b.*\n)/g
```

<kbd>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cu5swa/1)</kbd>

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` (?<=START[\s\S]+) ``` | Whatever follows literal "START", then one or more whitespace or non-whitespace can be a match |
| ``` \n␣␣ ``` | A newline, then two spaces¹ |
| ``` (Mr.+␣.+ ``` | Capture group $1: literal "Mr", then one or more of any char, then a space, then one or more of any char... |
| ``` \b.*\n) ``` | ...then a word char on the left and a non-word char on the right, then zero or more of any char, and finally a new line |

<sup><sup>1</sup>A space character is represented by a `␣`</sup>

```js
const str = `
qwer asdf asdf
Mr Bill Smith
qwer asdf asdf
  Mr Bob Smith
  START  
qwer asdf asdf
  Mr Correct1 Smith  
qwer asdf asdf
  Mr Correct2 Smith  
asldfj asldf 
`;
const rgx = /(?<=START[\s\S]+)\n  (Mr.+ .+\b.*\n)/g;

const res = str.match(rgx);

console.log(res.map(m => m.trim()));
```

Comment: thanks - I did get an error in regex101.com when running it fyi - "+ A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width"

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my answer, PCRE and Python does not accept quantifiers in look around, but JavaScript does [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/cu5swa/1)